# Which modules are required for the dynamic webform on webform.com?

Tags: webforms

I'd like to allow users to create webforms like the one on [webform.com](https://webform.com/content/add/webform).

> [image: screenshot]

Which modules are required? Is [Arrange Fields](https://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) one of them?

Comment: This kind of questions is [off-topic](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (See "Implementing a functionality, or a layout, seen in a site for which only a screenshot, or the site URL is provided.")

Answer (score 1):

The website is using the [Form Builder](https://drupal.org/project/form_builder) module.

> This project allows users to build entire Form API structures through a graphical, AJAX-like interface. It has the ability to read and export FAPI arrays, and users are permitted to change any properties exposed by modules that expose forms to the Form Builder.

Comment: + the webform module right?

Answer (score 0):

you could go through http://www.commercialprogression.com/post/drupal-webforms-dynamic-select-boxes-tutorial for creating webform dynamically.

Link tells you how to create dynamic drupal select boxes. It is done mainly in three steps which are to

1. Build your form with Webform Module.
2. Create a custom module to access your database.
3. Dynamically create and change select boxes on your form.